# One of my monitors is detected by X Server but does not display anything on screen. How do I fix TwinView?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, twinview, xserver

I just recovered from a white screen of death I was having by reinstalling my nvidia drivers via the command line in recovery mode. When I rebooted after that, everything was fine, except one of my monitors is not displaying anything.

I ran sudo nvidia xconfig, which created the conf file for me, but the issue was not resolved. In X Server Settings, the secondary monitor (the one not displaying), is detected and enabled in TwinView, but its resolution is not detected and the screen is black. If I try switching workspaces, the little window showing all workspaces show the second monitor sitting next to my monitor, same as in X Server Settings.

What options do I have for resolving this?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: My xorg conf has the following:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 302.17  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-04.nvidia.com)  Tue Jun 12 17:05:44 PDT 2012

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 302.17  (buildd@rhenium)  Sun Jun 17 23:26:33 UTC 2012

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE248"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 570"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try reseting the display variable ;
[this may help you](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1047029)

its good to check [Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55996/setting-screen-1-resolution-corrupts-screen-0) configuration by `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my post with the contents of my Xorg config.    Was the take-away from the forum post to try

    gksudo nvidia-settings

If so, it did not work.  If it's not, I'm not sure which advice to follow on there.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, I found the enabling Xinerama in the Nvida-settings fixed things for me.  it does however completely disable the "Display" function in settings...so I cannot remove the second task bar thing...